# Jigsaw Puzzle Code Not Running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Jigsaw Puzzle in Unity, replicating a tutorial off of YouTube by 'Game Design HQX'. I wrote out all the code from the first part of the tutorial and Unity will not run it and I don't understand why. Please help..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movepiece : MonoBehaviour {
    public string pieceStatus = "";

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (pieceStatus != "locked")
        {
            Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
            Vector2 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
            transform.position = objPosition;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == gameObject.name)
        {
            transform.position = other.gameObject.transform.position;
            pieceStatus = "locked";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error Unity gave me:
Assets/Movepiece.cs(28,34): error CS0103: The name `other' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
```

to:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
```

I recommend you to watch [Unity official tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) first. They are much better for begginers.

Answer (score 1):

> `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {`
>
> `if (other.gameObject.name == gameObject.name)`

You named the parameter `collision` instead of `other`.

Comment: which wouldnt be a problem, had he used collision instead of other as variable name in the code.

Comment: @yes either way

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing an `other` variable that doesn't exist in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, I think like others pointed out that you are referring to the collision variable when you use the `other` word so replace all the times you use other to collision or just change the collision variable name to other

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == gameObject.name)
    {
        transform.position = other.gameObject.transform.position;
        pieceStatus = "locked";
    }
}
```